# Numpy only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index - Upgrading to 3.6

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I'm reading in the `.flo` as I do some warping. Seems I have no issue with Python2.7 and numpy version 1.11.2, but when I upgrade to Python3.6 and numpy version 1.12.0.

But during the conversion, I know get an error `only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` for the line `data2d = np.fromfile(f, np.float32, count=2 * w * h)`

```
import numpy as np


def read_flow(filename):
        f = open(filename, 'rb')
        magic = np.fromfile(f, np.float32, count=1)
        data2d = None

        if 202021.25 != magic:
            print('Magic number incorrect. Invalid .flo file')
        else:
            w = np.fromfile(f, np.int32, count=1)
            h = np.fromfile(f, np.int32, count=1)
            print("Reading %d x %d flo file" % (h, w))
            data2d = np.fromfile(f, np.float32, count=2 * w * h)
            # reshape data into 3D array (columns, rows, channels)
            data2d = np.resize(data2d, (h, w, 2))
        f.close()
        return data2d
```

Example `.flo` file can be obtained [here](https://github.com/liruoteng/OpticalFlowToolkit/blob/master/data/example/flow_gt.flo)

Comment: try `count=int(2 * w * h)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga stops complaining, but now gives an empty array, so doesn't work as expected

Comment: Yes, well, can't diagnose from here without knowing the values of `w`, `h`, and what you expect `data2d` to be

Comment: You can obtain all of these through using the example .flo file that is available

Answer (score 3):

If I run your code using python 2.7 I get the following warning:

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: converting an array with ndim > 0 to an index will result in an error in the future return reshape(newshape, order=order)

The reason for this is that np.fromfile() returns a numpy array containing the data instead of just the data - even for single elements. That means w = np.fromfile(f, np.int32, count=1) is something like [512] instead of 512.

The following version should work for python 2.7 and 3.x

```
import numpy as np
def read_flow(filename):
        f = open(filename, 'rb')
        magic = np.fromfile(f, np.float32, count=1)
        data2d = None

        if 202021.25 != magic:
            print('Magic number incorrect. Invalid .flo file')
        else:
            w = np.fromfile(f, np.int32, count=1)[0]
            h = np.fromfile(f, np.int32, count=1)[0]
            print("Reading %d x %d flo file" % (h, w))
            data2d = np.fromfile(f, np.float32, count=2 * w * h)
            # reshape data into 3D array (columns, rows, channels)
            data2d = np.resize(data2d, (h, w, 2))
        f.close()
        return data2d
```